# Do we have stand alone application for pdf to epub3?

Tags: marklogic

There is JavaScript function in MarkLogic [xdmp.pdfConvert](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.pdfConvert).
I'm trying to convert pdf to epub3.

Basically I want to convert pdf into epub format (epub consist of XHTML page include there css and images). So the function in MarkLogic [xdmp.pdfConvert](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.pdfConvert) which takes pdf as input convert into XHTML as output.

Can you suggest the steps and requirements for how to execute that function? I want to see the quality of the converted output of XHTML as comparing with input pdf.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added some information please let me know if it is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in conversion from PDF to epub3 in MarkLogic. The pdfConvert function's primary purpose is to make the content of a PDF searchable.

I'm not familiar enough with the epub3 format to make a suggestion about generating it inside of MarkLogic, but my starting point would be to look for an external library that can already do it and use that.

---

Updating based on additional information:

You asked a similar question in the comments on the pdfCovert page (about how to use the function) and I pointed you to the [Understanding and Using the Default Conversion Option](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/default#id_28183) section of the CPF guide. Earlier in that same chapter, there is a section called [Installing the Conversion Pipelines and Framework](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cpf/default#id_89015). Please try those steps and let us know if you have a specific follow-up question.

Comment: So I'm asking about that content processing framework (CPF) which convert PDF into XHTML.  Can you suggest me the steps how to achieve that conversion. Because epub consist of xhtml along with the css and images so i want to see how effective this function can be.